# How to make pictures taken by my App backup-able

Tags: android, sqlite, android-camera, android-room

Lets say I have an App that allows me to rate mugs. Therefore, I enter some rating criterias, take a Picture of the mug and then save it to a DataBase, to look at it later.

At the moment, I save the picture on a path obtained by

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

and save the path to my SQLite database to look at it later.

This works fine, however, as I rate a hole bunch of mugs all day and change my phone quiet often, I want to be able to backup my App and its data by common Android backup solutions. This works fine with the SQLite Database that holds the data and is stored in App-Context.

But since the database just holds a path to the taken picture (as returned by getExternalFilesDir), the picture is not backed-up. Where do I have to save the picure, to ensure that any common Android backup software will also grap the pictures?

Is it possible to ensure that the path stored in the database is the same, after I put the backup on a new phone? Since it may be possible that the App is located somewhere else on the new phone, absolute paths are not a good idea here... Is it possible to save the picture relative to the App and just save the relative path?

Comment: `Is it possible to save the picture relative to the App and just save the relative path?`. Save only the path part relative to getExternalFilesDir(). Then later you can add the getExternalFilesDir() path before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by greenapps, a possible solution is to save just the relative path of the image in the database. Instead of using

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

I now use

```
getFilesDir()
```

to get the app intern folder and save images there. When I want to load the picture I build the path with the same method to get the app dir and the relative path saved in the database.